# How to apply Mean encoding in test set?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, deep-learning, feature-engineering

If I have a dataset, mean encoding is applied on training dataset's categorical feature 'A' by calculating mean of each of its category in context with target variable 'B'
But what about test data? Test data doesn't contain any target variable. Should I use calculated values from training data?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by mean encoding, but any feature engineering process that takes into account the target variables is an extremely bad idea (and arguably now you can guess at least one reason why).

Answer (score 1):

> Should I use calculated values from training data?

- Yes. In cases where test data isn't present in training data, the global mean can help. Though there are other methods to deal with the same for eg:  Using nested fold for target encoding.

Nested folds work as follows.

For each train/test split in the primary cv, split train in k secondary folds. The target encoding for each of the secondary k fold is computed from the target values of the k-1 remaining secondary folds. The target encoding for the test fold is computed from the target values of the train fold. k can be as low as 2.

More info on mean encoding : 
https://maxhalford.github.io/blog/target-encoding/

Good Discussion Here on different techniques : https://www.kaggle.com/c/porto-seguro-safe-driver-prediction/discussion/44987